# Rails collection_select is not accepting a :selected option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm using a `collection_select` to display the contents of a hash:

#### Hash

```
CATEGORY1_TEXT_STYLE = {
  'Normal' => 'normal',
  'Normal Centered' => 'normal center',
  'Bold' => 'bold'
  ...
}
```

#### Collection Select

```
= collection_select :category1_style1, :first, Homepage::CATEGORY1_TEXT_STYLE, :last, :first, options = { :selected => style_selected(@style.first) }
```

#### `style_selected` (from helper)

```
def style_selected(value)
  returnval = ''
  Homepage::CATEGORY1_TEXT_STYLE.each { |key, val| returnval = key if val == value }
  returnval
end
```

#### Controller

```
@style = Homepage.find(0).category1_style.gsub('-', '').split("\n")[1..-1]
```

This outputs: `[" bold center", " blue center", " normal center", " blue center"]`

It's confusing because I'm not sure how to get it to choose a selected value based on that hash. I've done it before using id values (numbers) and it works, but this key/value pair is both strings and the `:selected => ""` field doesn't seem to want to take a string to match again, whether it's a match for the key or the value (I've tried both).

Any insight on trying to have a collection select display a default selected value when dealing with strings?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `collection_select` inside a `form_for @something` or a `form_tag`? In any case, can you break down your call to `collection_select`, because I don't really understand what you're trying to do based on the way you're calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select#632--selected

> If you want some object to be selected by default, be sure to use its id, not the whole object.